# Writing bootsector in C: prevent generating stack pointer initialization

Tags: c, gcc, assembly, gnu-assembler, mbr

After tinkering with writing bootsector code in assembly, I'm wondering if I can do the same but in C. So far the code generation in an empty function looks as such:

in C:

```
void _start() {
halt:
    goto halt;
}
```

consequent asm (generated by GCC):

```
7c00:   55                      push   %bp
7c01:   89 e5                   mov    %sp,%bp
7c03:   eb fe                   jmp    0x7c03
```

However, is it possible to specify that for this (entry) function in particular, I do not want the base and stack pointer to be initialized? The BIOS will transfer control directly to 0x7c00, so the first two instructions setting up the stack pointers are redundant.

Ive tried adding `__attribute__ ((always_inline, noreturn, regparm(0)))` to the function declaration, but that does not seem to do anything.

Comment: Try increasing the optimisation level. `-O2` should do it.

Comment: The _asm_ code you are showing - is that what you created by hand or _GCC_?

Comment: Not tested, something like `-fomit-frame-pointer`?

Comment: In MSVC there's __declspec(naked). See if GCC has an equivalent to that. But note that a __declspec(naked) function may not declare local variables IIRC.

Comment: The attribute you're looking for is `naked` but GCC doesn't support that with x86 targets. Turning up the optimization will remove the stack frame allocation, but only if the compiler thinks it's not needed. Otherwise there's nothing you can do to remove it This, among other reasons, is why using a C compiler to write a bootsector is a bad idea.

Comment: Also, you're firmly out of the realm of "standard C" and into the realm of "praying the compiler generates what I want it to".

Comment: @RossRidge : or at least use a _C_ compiler that outputs proper 16-bit code that isn't full of gotchyas, and prefixes that aren't available on 8086/8088 processors. I'd avoid writing a bootsector with _GCC_ . Bruce's  C compiler (BCC), and Openwatcom, or if you are on Windows MSVC 1.52c (if you have a copy laying around).

Comment: I think the moment of truth for your code will be when you attempt to add a stack based variable or call functions. The output from your disassembly suggests to me you aren't using `-m16` (available on newer GCC's) or `__asm__(".code16gcc\n");` at the very top of your _C_ file(s). Unless you really know what you are doing (and the associated pitfalls) I wouldn't even seriously consider recommending that bad hack. What caught my eye is that there are no 0x66 or 0x67 prefixes in the disassembled code which suggests you are compiling your _C_ code as 32 or 64-bit code.

Comment: Considering GCC's popularity and general portability, I always thought there would be a way to get it to fully support 16 bit code generation - hence the numerous oversights and assumptions I've made. I'm not too keen on using extra tools, so I'll just stick with programming what I must in assembler.

Comment: GCC has had a .code16gcc directive that can be emitted for GNU assembler to interpret for about 15 years. As of about GCC 4.9.0 they finally added the `-m16` option (which pretty much does what .code16gcc did without specifying the directive manually).

Comment: Max: gcc can make code that runs in 16bit mode. That's **not** the only issue here: the ABI for a boot sector is way different from the normal function-call ABI.  There's no way to handle this without inline asm: even trying to use global register variables or something won't help with segment setup and an initial stack pointer.  Also most of what a first-stage bootloader has to do is make a bunch of `int` BIOS calls, which will require inline asm.  Since you only have 512b to work with, it's probably easier to write it in asm, since it can't be very many instructions anyway!

Answer (score 5):

I hate to discourage an admirable notion, but it's very difficult [if not impossible] to write a PC MBR boot block in C, for a few reasons, mostly having to do with the quirkiness of a PC/legacy BIOS boot:

1. The BIOS will load your block, but will then write into it at precise locations to provide information.  This is the "boot parameter block" [BPB].  Among other things, it has the drive number to boot from.
2. The BPB starts at offset 0x03.  So, the first 3 bytes of the must have a `jmp` asm instruction to skip around this.
3. The last two bytes of the sector must have the BIOS boot signature 0x55AA
4. There must be space at a precise location for the partition table [which will be overwritten by partition editors like `fdisk`

There's precious little space left over and the code is tricky and heavily tied to the BIOS.  You have to be able to use the `int` asm instructions to interrogate the BIOS and issue disk read calls.  They have a precise sequence and for some you must be able to modify the x86 *segment* registers as well as controlling the general purpose registers with byte loads (e.g. you must be able to set values in the `%ah` independently of `%al`).

Most boots [virtually all] write the boot sector in assembly.  In order to conserve space, some boot blocks execute some code and then overwrite that code with data because the code is executed once and the space is reused.  This is difficult to do in C.

By the time you've adjusted your C program, you may find out that it just doesn't fit in 512 bytes.

In the case of `grub`, its boot block loads a sector or two from the area after the boot block and transfers control.  That, using parameters set up by the boot block, reads in more of `grub`.  `grub` "co-opts" a portion of the "no man's land" from the 2nd sector up to the first partition [which starts at 1MB]. Then, transfers control, which then loads the remainder and decides how to boot the OS.  The later stages are written in C.

For Windows, the MBR would just load the first sector of the partition marked as bootable, then transfer control.  That second stage is NT's boot loader.  It knows that the first N blocks after it in an NTFS filesystem contain the remainder of the boot, so it just loads them sequentially and transfers control.

Note that the second stage boots have a bit of assembly, but after loading and probing a bit, they can and do switch to C code.  That approach is what I'd recommend.

---

As an example, here's the source for boot block for `grub2`:

```
/* -*-Asm-*- */
/*
 *  GRUB  --  GRand Unified Bootloader
 *  Copyright (C) 1999,2000,2001,2002,2005,2006,2007,2008,2009  Free Software Foundation, Inc.
 *
 *  GRUB is free software: you can redistribute it and/or modify
 *  it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
 *  the Free Software Foundation, either version 3 of the License, or
 *  (at your option) any later version.
 *
 *  GRUB is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
 *  but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
 *  MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
 *  GNU General Public License for more details.
 *
 *  You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
 *  along with GRUB.  If not, see <http://www.gnu.org/licenses/>.
 */

#include <grub/symbol.h>
#include <grub/machine/boot.h>

/*
 *  defines for the code go here
 */

        /* Print message string */
#define MSG(x)  movw $x, %si; call LOCAL(message)
#define ERR(x)  movw $x, %si; jmp LOCAL(error_message)

        .file   "boot.S"

        .text

        /* Tell GAS to generate 16-bit instructions so that this code works
           in real mode. */
        .code16

.globl _start, start;
_start:
start:
        /*
         * _start is loaded at 0x7c00 and is jumped to with CS:IP 0:0x7c00
         */

        /*
         * Beginning of the sector is compatible with the FAT/HPFS BIOS
         * parameter block.
         */

        jmp     LOCAL(after_BPB)
        nop     /* do I care about this ??? */

        /*
         * This space is for the BIOS parameter block!!!!  Don't change
         * the first jump, nor start the code anywhere but right after
         * this area.
         */

        . = _start + GRUB_BOOT_MACHINE_BPB_START
        . = _start + 4

        /* scratch space */
mode:
        .byte   0
disk_address_packet:
sectors:
        .long   0
heads:
        .long   0
cylinders:
        .word   0
sector_start:
        .byte   0
head_start:
        .byte   0
cylinder_start:
        .word   0
        /* more space... */

        . = _start + GRUB_BOOT_MACHINE_BPB_END

        /*
         * End of BIOS parameter block.
         */

kernel_address:
        .word   GRUB_BOOT_MACHINE_KERNEL_ADDR

        . = _start + GRUB_BOOT_MACHINE_KERNEL_SECTOR
kernel_sector:
        .long   1, 0

        . = _start + GRUB_BOOT_MACHINE_BOOT_DRIVE
boot_drive:
        .byte 0xff      /* the disk to load kernel from */
                        /* 0xff means use the boot drive */

LOCAL(after_BPB):

/* general setup */
        cli             /* we're not safe here! */

        /*
         * This is a workaround for buggy BIOSes which don't pass boot
         * drive correctly. If GRUB is installed into a HDD, check if
         * DL is masked correctly. If not, assume that the BIOS passed
         * a bogus value and set DL to 0x80, since this is the only
         * possible boot drive. If GRUB is installed into a floppy,
         * this does nothing (only jump).
         */
        . = _start + GRUB_BOOT_MACHINE_DRIVE_CHECK
boot_drive_check:
        jmp     3f      /* grub-setup may overwrite this jump */
        testb   $0x80, %dl
        jz      2f
3:
        /* Ignore %dl different from 0-0x0f and 0x80-0x8f.  */
        testb   $0x70, %dl
        jz      1f
2:
        movb    $0x80, %dl
1:
        /*
         * ljmp to the next instruction because some bogus BIOSes
         * jump to 07C0:0000 instead of 0000:7C00.
         */
        ljmp    $0, $real_start

real_start:

        /* set up %ds and %ss as offset from 0 */
        xorw    %ax, %ax
        movw    %ax, %ds
        movw    %ax, %ss

        /* set up the REAL stack */
        movw    $GRUB_BOOT_MACHINE_STACK_SEG, %sp

        sti             /* we're safe again */

        /*
         *  Check if we have a forced disk reference here
         */
        movb   boot_drive, %al
        cmpb    $0xff, %al
        je      1f
        movb    %al, %dl
1:
        /* save drive reference first thing! */
        pushw   %dx

        /* print a notification message on the screen */
        MSG(notification_string)

        /* set %si to the disk address packet */
        movw    $disk_address_packet, %si

        /* check if LBA is supported */
        movb    $0x41, %ah
        movw    $0x55aa, %bx
        int     $0x13

        /*
         *  %dl may have been clobbered by INT 13, AH=41H.
         *  This happens, for example, with AST BIOS 1.04.
         */
        popw    %dx
        pushw   %dx

        /* use CHS if fails */
        jc      LOCAL(chs_mode)
        cmpw    $0xaa55, %bx
        jne     LOCAL(chs_mode)

        andw    $1, %cx
        jz      LOCAL(chs_mode)

lba_mode:
        xorw    %ax, %ax
        movw    %ax, 4(%si)

        incw    %ax
        /* set the mode to non-zero */
        movb    %al, -1(%si)

        /* the blocks */
        movw    %ax, 2(%si)

        /* the size and the reserved byte */
        movw    $0x0010, (%si)

        /* the absolute address */
        movl    kernel_sector, %ebx
        movl    %ebx, 8(%si)
        movl    kernel_sector + 4, %ebx
        movl    %ebx, 12(%si)

        /* the segment of buffer address */
        movw    $GRUB_BOOT_MACHINE_BUFFER_SEG, 6(%si)

/*
 * BIOS call "INT 0x13 Function 0x42" to read sectors from disk into memory
 *      Call with       %ah = 0x42
 *                      %dl = drive number
 *                      %ds:%si = segment:offset of disk address packet
 *      Return:
 *                      %al = 0x0 on success; err code on failure
 */

        movb    $0x42, %ah
        int     $0x13

        /* LBA read is not supported, so fallback to CHS.  */
        jc      LOCAL(chs_mode)

        movw    $GRUB_BOOT_MACHINE_BUFFER_SEG, %bx
        jmp     LOCAL(copy_buffer)

LOCAL(chs_mode):
        /*
         *  Determine the hard disk geometry from the BIOS!
         *  We do this first, so that LS-120 IDE floppies work correctly.
         */
        movb    $8, %ah
        int     $0x13
        jnc     LOCAL(final_init)

        /*
         *  The call failed, so maybe use the floppy probe instead.
         */
        testb   $GRUB_BOOT_MACHINE_BIOS_HD_FLAG, %dl
        jz      LOCAL(floppy_probe)

        /* Nope, we definitely have a hard disk, and we're screwed. */
        ERR(hd_probe_error_string)

LOCAL(final_init):
        /* set the mode to zero */
        movzbl  %dh, %eax
        movb    %ah, -1(%si)

        /* save number of heads */
        incw    %ax
        movl    %eax, 4(%si)

        movzbw  %cl, %dx
        shlw    $2, %dx
        movb    %ch, %al
        movb    %dh, %ah

        /* save number of cylinders */
        incw    %ax
        movw    %ax, 8(%si)

        movzbw  %dl, %ax
        shrb    $2, %al

        /* save number of sectors */
        movl    %eax, (%si)

setup_sectors:
        /* load logical sector start (top half) */
        movl    kernel_sector + 4, %eax

        orl     %eax, %eax
        jnz     LOCAL(geometry_error)

        /* load logical sector start (bottom half) */
        movl    kernel_sector, %eax

        /* zero %edx */
        xorl    %edx, %edx

        /* divide by number of sectors */
        divl    (%si)

        /* save sector start */
        movb    %dl, %cl

        xorw    %dx, %dx        /* zero %edx */
        divl    4(%si)          /* divide by number of heads */

        /* do we need too many cylinders? */
        cmpw    8(%si), %ax
        jge     LOCAL(geometry_error)

        /* normalize sector start (1-based) */
        incb    %cl

        /* low bits of cylinder start */
        movb    %al, %ch

        /* high bits of cylinder start */
        xorb    %al, %al
        shrw    $2, %ax
        orb     %al, %cl

        /* save head start */
        movb    %dl, %al

        /* restore %dl */
        popw    %dx

        /* head start */
        movb    %al, %dh

/*
 * BIOS call "INT 0x13 Function 0x2" to read sectors from disk into memory
 *      Call with       %ah = 0x2
 *                      %al = number of sectors
 *                      %ch = cylinder
 *                      %cl = sector (bits 6-7 are high bits of "cylinder")
 *                      %dh = head
 *                      %dl = drive (0x80 for hard disk, 0x0 for floppy disk)
 *                      %es:%bx = segment:offset of buffer
 *      Return:
 *                      %al = 0x0 on success; err code on failure
 */

        movw    $GRUB_BOOT_MACHINE_BUFFER_SEG, %bx
        movw    %bx, %es        /* load %es segment with disk buffer */

        xorw    %bx, %bx        /* %bx = 0, put it at 0 in the segment */
        movw    $0x0201, %ax    /* function 2 */
        int     $0x13

        jc      LOCAL(read_error)

        movw    %es, %bx

LOCAL(copy_buffer):
        /*
         * We need to save %cx and %si because the startup code in
         * kernel uses them without initializing them.
         */
        pusha
        pushw   %ds

        movw    $0x100, %cx
        movw    %bx, %ds
        xorw    %si, %si
        movw    $GRUB_BOOT_MACHINE_KERNEL_ADDR, %di
        movw    %si, %es

        cld

        rep
        movsw

        popw    %ds
        popa

        /* boot kernel */
        jmp     *(kernel_address)

/* END OF MAIN LOOP */

/*
 * BIOS Geometry translation error (past the end of the disk geometry!).
 */
LOCAL(geometry_error):
        ERR(geometry_error_string)

/*
 * Read error on the disk.
 */
LOCAL(read_error):
        movw    $read_error_string, %si
LOCAL(error_message):
        call    LOCAL(message)
LOCAL(general_error):
        MSG(general_error_string)

/* go here when you need to stop the machine hard after an error condition */
        /* tell the BIOS a boot failure, which may result in no effect */
        int     $0x18
LOCAL(stop):
        jmp     LOCAL(stop)

notification_string:    .asciz "GRUB "
geometry_error_string:  .asciz "Geom"
hd_probe_error_string:  .asciz "Hard Disk"
read_error_string:      .asciz "Read"
general_error_string:   .asciz " Error\r\n"

/*
 * message: write the string pointed to by %si
 *
 *   WARNING: trashes %si, %ax, and %bx
 */

        /*
         * Use BIOS "int 10H Function 0Eh" to write character in teletype mode
         *      %ah = 0xe       %al = character
         *      %bh = page      %bl = foreground color (graphics modes)
         */
1:
        movw    $0x0001, %bx
        movb    $0xe, %ah
        int     $0x10           /* display a byte */
LOCAL(message):
        lodsb
        cmpb    $0, %al
        jne     1b      /* if not end of string, jmp to display */
        ret

        /*
         *  Windows NT breaks compatibility by embedding a magic
         *  number here.
         */

        . = _start + GRUB_BOOT_MACHINE_WINDOWS_NT_MAGIC
nt_magic:
        .long 0
        .word 0

        /*
         *  This is where an MBR would go if on a hard disk.  The code
         *  here isn't even referenced unless we're on a floppy.  Kinda
         *  sneaky, huh?
         */

        . = _start + GRUB_BOOT_MACHINE_PART_START
part_start:

probe_values:
        .byte   36, 18, 15, 9, 0

LOCAL(floppy_probe):
/*
 *  Perform floppy probe.
 */

        movw    $probe_values - 1, %si

LOCAL(probe_loop):
        /* reset floppy controller INT 13h AH=0 */
        xorw    %ax, %ax
        int     $0x13

        incw    %si
        movb    (%si), %cl

        /* if number of sectors is 0, display error and die */
        cmpb    $0, %cl
        jne     1f

/*
 * Floppy disk probe failure.
 */
        MSG(fd_probe_error_string)
        jmp     LOCAL(general_error)

/* "Floppy" */
fd_probe_error_string:  .asciz "Floppy"

1:
        /* perform read */
        movw    $GRUB_BOOT_MACHINE_BUFFER_SEG, %bx
        movw    %bx, %es
        xorw    %bx, %bx
        movw    $0x201, %ax
        movb    $0, %ch
        movb    $0, %dh
        int     $0x13

        /* if error, jump to "LOCAL(probe_loop)" */
        jc      LOCAL(probe_loop)

        /* %cl is already the correct value! */
        movb    $1, %dh
        movb    $79, %ch

        jmp     LOCAL(final_init)

        . = _start + GRUB_BOOT_MACHINE_PART_END

/* the last 2 bytes in the sector 0 contain the signature */
        .word   GRUB_BOOT_MACHINE_SIGNATURE
```

Comment: More importantly, the code generated by GCC will assume it's running in 32-bit mode. It will *sometimes* be parseable as 16-bit code, but it will not run as intended.

Comment: @duskwuff gcc has `-m16` which outputs an asm directive `.code16gcc` which allows the code to run in real mode, but that doesn't help the real problem.  IIRC, the early transfer of `grub2` into C assumes the `-m16` before switching to full 32 bit mode later.  In fact, it can flit in and out, similar to an [infamous] MS/Windows _thunk_ operation until it's loaded and configured enough to stay in 32 bit for the remainder.

Comment: The `-m16` or the `.code16gcc` have quirks you need to be aware of, and the prefixes generated will not function on anything less than a 386 processor (code won't execute properly on 8086/88/188/286). That might not be a problem for some who don't ever intend booting from older PCs. Those extra prefixes (generated by -m16 or .code16gcc) also bloat the size of the bootloader. I've written Fat12 aware bootloaders in Openwatcom without a problem. Writing a bootloader in C isn't bad if you use the right compilers.

Comment: @MichaelPetch Obviously, I wasn't advocating it, merely mentioning the option exists in gcc.  It's a bit hard to find pre-386 motherboards that still work.  My 386 motherboard from 1996 gave it up [dead air] circa 2010.  Even harder to find 8086's still in service that OP would have access to or desire for.  They're too ancient even for used/surplus computer outlets (e.g. weirdstuff.com)

Answer (score 1):

Actually, it is posible to write a boot sector program almost entirely
in C;

Suppose you had the following files in the same directory;

linker.ld;

```
ENTRY (_start)
OUTPUT_FORMAT (binary)
SECTIONS
{
    . = 0x7c00;
    .text : { boot.o(.text)
              *(.text)
            }
    .rodata : { *(.rodata)
          }
    .data : { *(.data)
            }
    . = 0x7dfe;
    .boot_sig : { boot.o(.boot_sig);
            }
    .bss : { *(.bss)
           }
    . = ALIGN (0x200);
    lit = .;

    /DISCARD/ : { *(.eh_frame)
              *(.comment)
              *(.note.GNU-stack)
            }
}
```

Makefile;

```
progname    = boot-sector
# --------------------------------------------------------------------
# compiler/linker options;
# --------------------------------------------------------------------

# C programming
SHELL       = /bin/bash
CC      = gcc
defs        =
include_dirs    = -I../include
CFLAGS      = -Wall -mno-red-zone -Wextra -Os -ffreestanding -m16
CPPFLAGS    = -Wp,-Wall,-Wextra $(defs) $(include_dirs)
LDFLAGS     = -Wl,-Map=$@.map -T linker.ld -nostartfiles -nostdlib
LDLIBS      = 
# bison/flex options
YACC        = bison
YFLAGS      = -d
LEX     = flex
LFLAGS      = --full

# The rest of this file is the programmatic part of this makefile. 
######################################################################
# Preperation for flex/bison files
ysource     = $(wildcard *.y)
lexsource   = $(wildcard *.lex)
ycsource    = $(patsubst %.y,   %.tab.c,    $(ysource))
lexcsource  = $(patsubst %.lex, %.yy.c,     $(lexsource))

# --------------------------------------------------------------------
# source and object defitions corresponding to the built in and user
# defined implicit rules of interest to this makefile.
# (e.g. .c.o: )
# --------------------------------------------------------------------
csource     = $(ycsource) $(lexcsource) $(wildcard *.c)
gaSsource   = $(wildcard *.S)
source      = $(gaSsource) $(csource)
# IF YOU ADD A NEW AUTOMATIC RULE FOR A SOURCE ABOVE, YOU MUST ADD A
# AN ENTRY BELOW FOR THE OBJECT FILE:
cobjects    := $(patsubst %.c,  %.o,    $(csource))
gaSobjects  := $(patsubst %.S,  %.o,    $(gaSsource))
objects = $(gaSobjects) $(cobjects)

#
# REMEMBER TO DEFINE A NEW IMPLICIT RULE AT THE END OF THIS FILE FOR
# YOUR NEW FILENAME EXTENSION, IF IT IS NOT A BUILT IN EXPLICIT RULE
#

# --------------------------------------------------------------------
# DEFAULT RULE, THIS RULE MUST BE FIRST
# --------------------------------------------------------------------
all : $(progname)

# --------------------------------------------------------------------
# phony targets
# --------------------------------------------------------------------
.PHONY : clean
clean :
# Only use shell wild cards in rm operations.  Using $(objects) may
# cause project files to be deleted if there is anything wrong with
# the value of $(objects).
    rm -f $(progname) $(progname).so *.o *.d time-stamp
    find . -name '*~' -print0 | xargs -0 rm -f

# --------------------------------------------------------------------
# program targets
# --------------------------------------------------------------------
include $(csource:.c=.d) $(gaSsource:.S=.d)

$(progname) : $(objects)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS)  -o $@ $^ $(LDLIBS)
    touch time-stamp

# CUSTOM RULES CAN BE DEFINED BETWEEN HERE AND THE NEXT WARNING
# COMMENT.

# custom rules here :D

# 
# %.o : %.c is a built in implicit rule.
# %.o : %.C is a built in implicit rule.
# 
# ADD MORE IMPLICIT RULES BELOW AS NECESSARY
%.d: %.c Makefile linker.ld
    @set -e; rm -f $@; \
    $(CC) -MM $(CPPFLAGS) $< > $@.$$$$; \
    sed 's,\($*\)\.o[ :]*,\1.o $@ : ,g' < $@.$$$$ > $@; \
    rm -f $@.$$$$
%.d: %.S Makefile linker.ld
    @set -e; rm -f $@; \
    $(CC) -MM $(CPPFLAGS) $< > $@.$$$$; \
    sed 's,\($*\)\.o[ :]*,\1.o $@ : ,g' < $@.$$$$ > $@; \
    rm -f $@.$$$$
%.o : %.c Makefile linker.ld
    $(CC) $(CPPFLAGS) $(CFLAGS) -c -o $@ $<
%.o : %.S Makefile linker.ld
    $(CC) $(CPPFLAGS) $(CFLAGS) -c -o $@ $<
%.tab.c : %.y Makefile
    $(YACC) $(YFLAGS)  $<
%.yy.c : %.lex Makefile
    $(LEX) $(LFLAGS)  -o $@ $<
```

boot.S;

```
#define STACK_TOP 0x8000
#define BUFFER_SIZE 0x200;
    ## -----------------------------------------------------------
    ## Start up code for boot sector program.
    .text
    .code16
_start:
    .global _start
    ljmp $(0),$(set_segment)
set_segment:
    xorw %ax, %ax
    movw %ax, %ds
    movw %ax, %es
    movw %ax, %fs
    movw %ax, %fs
    movl $(STACK_TOP), %esp
    movl %esp, %ebp
    call cmain
1:
    hlt
    jmp 1b

    ## -----------------------------------------------------------
    ## Boot Signature --- in this software project, there is no
    ## DOS partition table.  Instead, the partition table will be
    ## found in the sector immediately following all of the boot
    ## loader code.
    .section .boot_sig, "a"
    .short 0xaa55
```

main.c;

```
/* main.c - Boot sector program. */
/* Copyright (C) 2017 Robin Miyagi
 *
 * This program is free software; you can redistribute it and/or
 * modify it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as
 * published by the Free Software Foundation; either version 3 of the
 * License, or (at your option) any later version.
 *
 * This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful, but
 * WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
 * MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the GNU
 * General Public License for more details.
 *
 * You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
 * along with this program; if not, write to the Free Software
 * Foundation, Inc., 675 Mass Ave, Cambridge, MA 02139, USA.
 */
/********************************************************************/
/*                                                                  */
/*             Project Includes                         */
/*                                                                  */
/********************************************************************/
/********************************************************************/
/*                                                                  */
/*             System Includes                          */
/*                                                                  */
/********************************************************************/
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stddef.h>

/********************************************************************/
/*                                                                  */
/*            Macro Definitions                         */
/*                                                                  */
/********************************************************************/
#define SECTOR_SIZE 0x200
/********************************************************************/
/*                                                                  */
/*                Data Types                            */
/*                                                                  */
/********************************************************************/
/*  
 * Type definition and structure for the address packet used for LBA
 * disk addressing.
 */
typedef struct address_packet_struct address_packet_T;
struct address_packet_struct
{
  uint8_t size;         /* Size of this address packet. */
  uint8_t mbz;          /* Must be zero. */
  uint16_t sectors;     /* Number of sectors to transfer. */
  uint32_t buffer;      /* Transfer buffer - see note #1. */
  uint32_t lba_lower;       /* Lower 32 bits of starting LBA. */
  uint32_t lba_upper;       /* Upper 32 bits of starting LBA. */
} __attribute__((__packed__));
/* Notes: --------------------------------------------------------- */
/*   
 *   1.  The segment is in the upper 16 bits of `buffer', and the
 *       offset is in the lower 16 bits of `buffer'.
 */
typedef struct packed_int_struct packed_int_T;
struct packed_int_struct
{
  uint32_t lba_lower;
  uint32_t lba_upper;
} __attribute__((__packed__));
/*
 * Type definition and union for LBA disk address.
 */
typedef union disk_address_union disk_address_T;
union disk_address_union
{
  uint64_t l;
  packed_int_T dwords;
};

/*
 * Type definition and structure for segment/offset.
 */
typedef struct segment_struct segment_T;
struct segment_struct
{
  uint16_t offset;
  uint16_t segment;
} __attribute__ ((__packed__));

/*
 * Type definition and union for calculating segment/offset from a
 * pointer;
 */
typedef union address_calculator_union address_calculator_T;
union address_calculator_union
{
  void *ptr;
  uint32_t i;
  segment_T segoff;
};
/*
 * Type definition for loader "function"  
 */
typedef void (*loader_T) (void);
/*
 * Type definition and structure for load image table (LIT).
 */
typedef struct load_table_struct load_table_T;
struct load_table_struct
{
  loader_T entry;
  void *edata;
} __attribute__((packed));

/********************************************************************/
/*                                                                  */
/*             Global Variables                         */
/*                                                                  */
/********************************************************************/
/* Implemented in the linker script `linker.ld', this is the loader
 * information table.
 */
extern load_table_T lit;

/********************************************************************/
/*                                                                  */
/*             Module Variables                         */
/*                                                                  */
/********************************************************************/
/*
 * This is the disk address packet (DAP).
 */
__attribute__((__aligned__(4) )) static address_packet_T dap;

/********************************************************************/
/*                                                                  */
/*           Interface Functions                        */
/*                                                                  */
/********************************************************************/
/*
 * The main driver function for the boot sector program. 
 */
void cmain (void);

/********************************************************************/
/*                                                                  */
/*             Module Functions                         */
/*                                                                  */
/********************************************************************/
/* Text output functions........................................... */
/*
 * Prints a single character CH to the console. 
 */
static void putchar (char ch);

/*
 * Prints string S to the console.
 */
static void puts (char *s);

/*
 * Prints the error message specified in MESSAGE and halts the
 * processor.
 */
__attribute__((__noreturn__)) static void error (char *message);

/*  Loader functions............................................... */
/*
 * Tests if LBA extensions are available.  If LBA extensions are
 * supported, returns true, otherwise it returns false.
 */
static bool test_lba (void);

/*
 * Reads drive.  If successful, returns true, otherwise it returns
 * false.
 */
static bool read_drive (uint64_t lba, uint16_t sectors, void *buffer);

/*
 * Set up DAP. 
 */
static void setup_dap (uint64_t lba, uint16_t sectors, void *buffer);
/********************************************************************/
/*                                                                  */
/*             Inline Functions                         */
/*                                                                  */
/********************************************************************/
/********************************************************************/
/*                                                                  */
/*              Implementation                          */
/*                                                                  */
/********************************************************************/
void 
cmain (void)
{
  uint16_t sectors;

  if (test_lba () == false)
    error ("LBA not supported");
  if (read_drive (1, 1, &lit) == false)
    error ("Unable to read drive");
  sectors = ((uint32_t) lit.edata - (uint32_t) &lit) / 0x200 - 1;
  if (sectors > 0)
    {
      if (read_drive (2, sectors, (void *) &lit + SECTOR_SIZE) == false)
    error ("Unable to read drive");
    }
  lit.entry ();
}
static void 
putchar (char ch)
{
#define COLOR 0x7f
  int16_t buffer = 0x0e00;

  buffer += ch;
  asm ("int $(0x10)" 
       : 
       : "a" (buffer), "b" ((uint16_t) COLOR)
       :
       );
}
static void
puts (char *s)
{
  char *ptr;
  for (ptr = s; *ptr != '\0'; ++ptr)
    putchar (*ptr);
}
__attribute__((noreturn)) static void 
error (char *message)
{
  puts (message);
  puts (": processor halted");
  for (;;)
    asm ("hlt");
}
static bool
test_lba (void)
{
  bool ret = true;

  asm goto ("int $(0x10); jc %l3"
        : 
        : "a" ((uint16_t) 0x4100), "b" ((uint16_t) 0x55aa), "d" ((uint8_t) 0x80)
        :
        : lba_unsupported
        );
 quit:
  return ret;
 lba_unsupported:
  asm ("clc");
  ret = false;
  goto quit;
}
static bool
read_drive (uint64_t lba, uint16_t sectors, void *buffer)
{
  bool ret = true;

  setup_dap (lba, sectors, buffer);
  asm goto ("int $(0x13); jc %l3"
        :
        : "a" ((uint16_t) 0x4200), "d" ((uint8_t) 0x80), "S" (&dap)
        :
        : read_error
        );
 quit:
  return ret;
 read_error:
  ret = false;
  goto quit;
}
static void
setup_dap (uint64_t lba, uint16_t sectors, void *buffer)
{
  disk_address_T addr;
  address_calculator_T calculator;

  /*
   * Setup simple fields in DAP. 
   */
  dap.size = sizeof (address_packet_T);
  dap.mbz = 0;
  dap.sectors = sectors;

  /*
   * Setup buffer.
   */
  calculator.ptr = buffer;
  calculator.segoff.segment <<= 12;
  dap.buffer = calculator.i;

  /*
   * Setup LBA address. 
   */
  addr.l = lba;
  dap.lba_lower = addr.dwords.lba_lower;
  dap.lba_upper = addr.dwords.lba_upper;
}
```

Comment: You might want to move that LJMP instruction so that it's not the first instruction as it could be detected as the start of BPB by some BIOSes that update the BPB in boot blocks. There's no need to initialize FS, but you should initialize SS.